ASP.Net C# URL routing not working - Seems to just redirect
I am trying to use routing to pick up a variable and use it within the page default.aspx, but all it seems to be doing is redirecting the application to the page instead because it changes the URL to goto default.aspx instead of retaining what I put in.
Also there are no items in RouteData.Values either.
So I would nav to the url http://site/XYZ but then changes the url to http://site/Default.aspx
Am I missing something really obvious here?
Global.asax.cs
        public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            
            routes.MapPageRoute("RedirectionRoute", "{application}", "~/default.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary(new { application = "CMT" }));

        }

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            Application["dbServer"] = webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["dbServer"].Value;
            Application["siteCode"] = webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["siteCode"].Value;
            Application["targetNetwork"] = webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["targetNetwork"].Value;
            Application["defaultTheme"] = webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["defaultTheme"].Value;
            Application["basicPermission"] = SQLDB.FetchSingleValue("SELECT TOP 1 PermissionLevelID FROM PermissionLevels ORDER BY PermissionLevelID ASC", Central.userDB);
            Application["ApplicationID"] = SQLDB.FetchSingleValue("SELECT ApplicationID FROM WebApplication WHERE Applicationcode = '" + Application["siteCode"] + "'", Central.adminDB);
            Application["ApplicationTitle"] = SQLDB.FetchSingleValue("SELECT ApplicationName FROM WebApplication WHERE Applicationcode = '" + Application["siteCode"] + "'", Central.adminDB);

            fiveminuteTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            fiveminuteTimer.Start();
        }


Can anyone help me? Still having the same issue and don't understand why
